# Python what does this code do? list = list[ list != value]

Tags: python

As seen in the title, `ans_list` is a list of answers, `ans_index` is a number (the index of answer in a vocabulary but that's irrelevant atm)

What is the resulting `tree.anslist` here? (just for the first for example), ignore the iteration.

```
for tree in train_trees:
    tree.ans_list = ans_list[ans_list != tree.ans_ind]
```

I tried some codes myself but with no success to derive any meaning

**UPDATE:** I missed a line of code that changed a list of numbers into an array.

```
ans_list = array([vocab.index(ans) for ans in ans_list])
```

Comment: try to cast `True` and `False` to integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really show us what `ans_list` and `train_trees` are. The expression

```
ans_list[ans_list != tree.ans_ind]
```

looks very much like numpy arrays, which behave differently than Python lists:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ans_list = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> ans_ind = 3
>>> ans_list[ans_list != ans_ind]
array([1, 2, 4, 5])
```

Looks to me like you're trying to understand someone else's code by doing some tests that have nothing to do with that code.

Comment: This is almost definitely the right answer; why else would the author continue calling the variable `ans_list` if the logic selected a scalar value?

Comment: oh yeah, I missed a line of code that changed ans_list from a list to an array... ans_list = array([vocab.index(ans) for ans in ans_list])

This is the behaviour I expected from the code, but the naming scheme was obviously poorly chosen in the source code

Answer (score 4):

ans_list != tree.ans_ind is a boolean.  True and False are represented under the hood as the integers 0 and 1 (it's an old tradition that dates back to non-strongly typed languages, e.g. the c language does it).  So it returns the first or second item in the list depending on whether the boolean statement is true or false.

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l[False]
'a'
>>> l[True]
'b'
```

Comment: Also don't use l as a variable name (as I have done).. it looks too much like the number 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let us check why `True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` is equivalent to `0`

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> True == 0
False
>>> False == 0
True
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
```